# Best Way to Replace an <a> tag with JQuery via Google Optimize

Tags: jquery, google-optimize

trying to replace an  element without using using Jquery's .replaceWith() which drops the click even bindings.  This seems to work, but when the dom element is viewed in the browser, it appears different, and code tick marks have been altered. This causes the data to not be submitted. It this an Optimize issue or a Browser Issue? What's a better way to handle this?

**Original Code:**

```
$('CSS-PATH-TO-ELEMENT > ul > li').html("<a href='/PATH-TO-PAGE' class='active-trail link--internal' onclick='Drupal.behaviors.Analytics.navClick('Header','Compare Our Courses')' title='Compare Our Courses'>Compare Our Courses</a>");
```

**Rendered Code (Chrome)**
*Notice the difference inside the navClick()*

```
<a href="/PATH-TO-PAGE" class="active-trail link--internal" onclick="Drupal.behaviors.Analytics.navClick(" header','compare our courses')' title="Compare Our Courses">Compare Our Courses</a>");
```

**Renderd Code (Firefox)** *Notice the difference inside the navClick()*

```
<a href="/PATH-TO-PAGE" class="active-trail link--internal" onclick="Drupal.behaviors.Analytics.navClick(" header','compare="" our="" courses')'="" title="Compare Our Courses">Compare Our Courses</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the same quotes in onclick and parameters

You can try with this:

```
$('CSS-PATH-TO-ELEMENT > ul > li').html("<a href='/PATH-TO-PAGE' class='active-trail link--internal' onclick=\"Drupal.behaviors.Analytics.navClick('Header','Compare Our Courses')\" title='Compare Our Courses'>Compare Our Courses</a>");
```